# How to convert tflite model from unquanted to quant/ realtime image classifier react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have copied a react native code from [here](https://medium.com/@namar/high-performance-image-classification-with-react-native-336db0a96cd)

then i have created a deeplearning model using keras and converted it to tflite (they had used mobilenet quant model ) and replaced the code's model with mine and replaced the output.JSON with mine. App launches successfully with stucked predictions. I am new to react native and want to implement my keras or tflite models in react native can any one help me with this.. as there is no example code for realtime image classification in react native with custom models . plz help

Answer (score 0):

when i created tflite model with same dataset using teachablemachine of google the saved my model name as mask_unquant.tflite . i think there is something with quant and unquant.